# How to ensure publishing a message into a topic occurs within a transaction?

Tags: java, transactions, jms, spring-transactions, spring-jms

So here is the requirement.

1. The process of publishing messages into a topic should occur within a transaction
2. If the transaction succeeds then we return 0
3. If the transaction fails then we return 1

I know how to publish messages into a topic. I am using JMS template to publish into topic.

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, event);
```

But how can I make sure this is within a transaction? Can someone use code and explain the above requirement?

I have searched similar questions for a possible solution to my query, but they are not the ones which resolves my issue. Please do not point to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
template.setSessionTransacted(true).
```

If the commit fails, an exception is thrown.